# Querying data from DB using node js and printing outside the if else statement

Tags: node.js

I have the below code that works well to fetch data from DB and console log it..

I am however unable to call the variable outside the if else statement or in another file and it keeps saying `ReferenceError: query1 is not defined`

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const client =  new Client({
   user: user,
   database: db,
   password: password,
   port: port,
   host: host
   });

client.connect();


client.query(`select * from table`, (err, res) => {
if (!err){
    const query1 = res.rows;
    console.log(query1);
} else {
    console.log(err.message);
 }
});
```